# onprogressupdate method is not calling in asyncstask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have this class and in this class I try to call `onprogressupdate()` methode of `asynctask` but it's not getting called from `doInBackground()` method......and I checked by `logcat` problem is that in calling `onprogressupdate()` only....i don't know why it's not calling that method..help for this..

```
public class AsyncTaskLoadFiles extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

File targetDirector;
GalleryAdapter myTaskAdapter;

public AsyncTaskLoadFiles(GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter) {
    myTaskAdapter = galleryAdapter;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

    String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/Download/";
    targetDirector = new File(targetPath);
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {

    }
    myTaskAdapter.clear();
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
    File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();

    for (File file : files) {
        Log.i("INBA", file.getAbsolutePath());
        publishProgress(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    Log.i("progress", "values " + values[0]);
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

}

Comment: is Log.i("INBA", file.getAbsolutePath()); printing?

Comment: yes...it is printing...

Comment: I/INBA(1480): /storage/emulated/0/Download/download (1).jpg
I/INBA(1480): /storage/emulated/0/Download/images (2).jpg
I/INBA(1480): /storage/emulated/0/Download/1939906_710350969006310_1319798480484162085_n.jpg
I/INBA(1480): /storage/emulated/0/Download/images.jpg

Comment: remove     super.onPreExecute(); and     super.onProgressUpdate(values);